# Notation for concat in set theory

Tags: concatenation, automata-theory

I'm working on homework for a automata theory class. So far its just proofs involving regular expression nothing too crazy. Anyway, my question is this what is the proper set notation for concatenation? For example I know R + S would be the same as R union S but for the the life of me I can't remember what the set theory equivalent to concatenation is.

I'm not going to post any problems as I think I'll be fine working on them, could anyone give me a little nudge in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're referring to the concatenation of regular sets. Usually, either *concatenation* or the *dot* operator denotes the concatenation of regular sets. The same notation applies to regular expressions. For instance

- AB = A·B = { xy : x ∈ A & y ∈ B }

Formally, the regular sets form a Kleene algebra, which is an idempotent semiring with the Kleene star operator that satisfies a collection of axioms. In algebras like an idempotent semiring, multiplication is usually expressed *via* concatenation or the dot operator. This is why concatenation of regular sets - the multiplication operation in the Kleene algebra - is denoted by concatenation or the dot operator. The same is true of regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've found an example using concatenation in the book we are using. It basically used the principles you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

R + S is not the same as R union S, because strings are not sets. Strings are on an *alphabet* which is a set. (Though technically you could represent a string as a set of ordered pairs (char, index)).

You should just say R + S when you mean to concatenate. You cannot concatenate general sets.

However, you *can* concatenate *sets of strings*. For sets of strings U and V, the *concatenation*, UV consists of all strings of the form uv where u is a string from U and v is a string from V. It's a bit like a cross-product.

Comment: This is incorrect: when referring to regular expressions, it is customary to express their union using either the plus or union sign; when referring to regular sets, it is customary to express their union using the union sign.